# How do I compare floating point numbers

Tags: java, floating-point

Please forgive the obvious "I should probably already know this" element to the question but I'm not seeing a method that I would run the division side of this evaluation through, to get the result to come back as true.

I'm looking for a function that would return the result as a float of specific precision, so that the following would work...

```
float a = 0.66;

if( magicPrecisionFunction(2.0f/3.0f , 2) == a){ //the 2 specifies the level of precision
   //something
}
```

I realize that I can write this myself in 2 minutes, but I was hoping to find a Java native way to do this "properly".

Comment: Using double or float, you will never have a precise value for floating point numbers. If you want to handle these numbers, use `BigDecimal` instead. Sorry to say but yes, this is a *you should probably already know this*.

Comment: I don't think you mean irrational numbers. Every finite number you can represent in a floating type is rational.

Comment: AFAIK you can round the result. If you see the [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) documentation you can achieve this using [`BigDecimal#setScale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: AH! so that's the secret to BigDecimal.  Good to know! thanks very much.

Comment: Could you please change the title to "how do I compare rational numbers" :) I already tried to edit but it was denied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing floating point numbers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923682/comparing-floating-point-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want precision I wouldn't use `float` as `double` is simpler to write and gives you half a trillion times the accuracy.

Similar to @rofl's example

```
int n = 2, d = 3;
if ((long)(100.0 * n / d) == 66) {
  ...
}
```

Not only is this about 100x faster than using BigDecimal, the code is shorter to write.

BTW The proper way to to convert a double to a BigDecimal is to use valueOf

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1);
System.out.println(bd); // prints 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), it will do exactly what you need, 
you can create the number you need and set the precision with MathContext

```
    BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("2.0");
    BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal("3.0");
    BigDecimal ans = b1.divide(b2, new MathContext(2)); // 2 is precision
```

Comment: Interesting. You pass in a String to get back your resulting object?

Comment: you dont have to pass a string, this constructor can take many classes, take a look at it

Comment: @Dr.Dredel because if you pass a `double` or a `float` the `BigDecimal` instance will work with the wrong number i.e. 0.1 could be 0.9999999...

Comment: yes doubles are very bad, you should always work with BigDecimal if you need precise calculations

Comment: @Dr.Dredel this is critical if you will work in financial applications (just to let you know and don't want to break a financial system (= ).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Which is why most investment banks and trading houses use `double` or `long`. ;)  Note: C & C++ don't have decimal and are widely used for financial applications.

Answer (score 1):

how abut...

```
if (Math.round(100.0f * 2.0f/3.0f) == 66) {
  ..
}
```

EDIT: Ahhh... missed the point... not round, but truncatte. in which case:

```
if ((int)(100.0f * 2.0f / 3.0f) == 66) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: What made you think it couldn't return 67?

Comment: yeah, I think Math.floor would work, and again, as I said, I can write something like this myself, but I was curious if there was a built in Java mechanism to handle this.

Comment: BigDicimald are the sledge-hammer answer, big and **slow**. Yoy will notice the impact in a tight loop....