# Assertion failing even though the values seem to match

Tags: java, automated-tests, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

```
public void ClaimValidation() {

   float validateMemberPay = S3_1Response.jsonPath().get("planCopayAmount");
   softAssert.assertEquals(validateMemberPay, 300.00);
   float validatePlanPay = S3_1Response.jsonPath().get("planPayAmount");
   softAssert.assertEquals(validatePlanPay, 800.00, assertionMessage);
softAssert.AssertAll();
```

expected [300.0] but found [300.0],

ASSERTION HAS FAILED expected [800.0] but found [800.0]

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason, but `300.00` is a `double`-literal; `300.00f` would be a `float`-literal. --- I strongly recommend to use neither `float` nor `double` for anything money- and currency-related.

Comment: you cannot compare floating point numbers directly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923682/comparing-floating-point-numbers-in-java