# Comparing two fixed doubles with <, =, >. Is there really an issue?

Tags: java, numbers, compare, theory, point

I'd like to check if a `double` is smaller, equal to, or bigger than another `double`. Even though I read a lot about `floats` and `doubles` not being precisely comparable because of how the computer calculates at a binary level, using the simple binary operators works like a charm so far. I tested it with dozens of different numbers and it hasn't failed me even once so far.

So is there really a problem comparing them like that in my case? And if there is - why can't I locate it and how to fix it?

EDIT: I'm aware that `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` if I decide to compare them. The thing is - I want to simply compare two **fixed** `doubles`. I won't have to compare `0.1 + 0.2` and `0.3`. I'd have to compare `0.3` and `0.3` at best. Or `0.4` and `0.3`. Something like that. Do I really need to use BigDecimal, or epsilon, or whatever for that?

Comment: You'll definitely run into problems if you compare with `=`. Less so with `==`, but still problematic. Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1288 for one concrete example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating and comparing floating points in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896013/manipulating-and-comparing-floating-points-in-java)

Comment: @BiltheLizard I've already seen that. The thing is.. I simply have two fixed(!) double numbers.. I'm not doing any operations but comperative on them. That's where my question rises from! Editted my OP as well!

Comment: `double`'s that really are equal will also really compare equal (except `NaN`).

Comment: The `==` operator _does_ compare double values for equality.  If you assign `x=0.3`, then `x == 0.3` will be `true`.  All of the negative answers below are rightly warning you that programmers have _often_ introduced bugs into code by thinking of `double` as a kind of Real, and wrongly _expecting_ a particular result from some computation under some particular circumstance.    (E.g., if you think that `for(x=0.0;x!=0.3;x+=0.1)` is ever going to terminate, think again!) Use `==`  _wisely_, and use unit-tests and `asserts` to prove to other programmers that you knew what you were doing.

Answer (score 2):

`double`s are a discrete representation of decimal numbers. That means that not all numbers can be represented by a double.

For example `double` can't represent some very large numbers accurately, in which case they are "rounded" to the closest available double. See for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double d1 = 1e50;
  double d2 = d1 + 1;
  System.out.println(d2 > d1); //false
  System.out.println(d2 == d1); //true
}
```

Comment: @user3213110 My answer to your edit is the same: you may expect d2 to be greater than d1 in my example but it's not from Java's perspective. This may or may not be an issue for what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example when using float can cause an error.

```
System.out.println(1.0 - 0.2 - 0.3 - 0.4 - 0.1); // Is not 0.0
```

If you need decimal numbers with arbitrary precision use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<` and `>` operators aren't a problem.

It's the `==` operator that's going to create issues with any real data.  So you haven't had a problem yet?  Well, you can run around on a golf course during a thunderstorm waving a club over your head and not get struck by lightning, too.  Doesn't mean you won't be.

Answer (score 0):

`double`'s *are* precisely comparable. Problems arise mainly because of two reasons

1. many people assume that math with `double`'s works the same as math with Reals. It does not. Many assumptions about what things should be exactly equal do not easily (or at all) translate from Reals to `double`'s.
2. "funny things" such as Extended Precision activating unpredictably (use `strictfp`)

As usual, the other answers are wrong. A `double` does not "represent" a range of numbers (you can pretend they do, but ultimately a `double` only has one exact value and no notion of what sort of "range" it is meant to represent). The answer showing that equality for `double`'s can have "funny results" is correct insofar that the result is "funny", but the problem there is with the *expected result*, not the result itself. If you expect the right thing, there is no problem there.

Comment: Oh?  Run this and tell us what you get:  

`#include <limits.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>  
  
int main( int argc, char **argv )  
{  
    uint64_t ii = UINT64_MAX;  
    double aa = (double) ii/0.0001;  
    ii--;  
    double bb = (double) ii/ 0.0001;  
    if ( aa == bb )  
        printf( "Hey, they're \"equal\"!\n" );  
    return( 0 );  
}`  
  
Stating that a double value "does not "represent" a range of numbers" is disingenuous at best.  For every "precise" double value, there is a range of real numbers that can only be represented by that one value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle of course there is a range of reals closest to any given double (well, except infinities and nan). This is also true of ints. That doesn't mean either of them *are* ranges, if you interpret them that way then that is merely an interpretation (and a dangerous one at that).