# StreamTokenizer input number and parsed number are different

Tags: java, token

I have a StreamTokenizer that accepts numbers. However, the parsed number is not the same as the input.

Sample code:

```
String str = "1000000000000.0000000000000";
double initial = 1000000000000.0000000000000;
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
StreamTokenizer input = new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)));
input.parseNumbers();
int n = input.nextToken();
if (n == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
    System.out.println("Original: " + str);
    System.out.println("Parsed: " + input.nval);
    System.out.println(initial + " == " + input.nval + " -> " + (initial == input.nval));
}
```

Output:

```
Original: 1000000000000.0000000000000
Parsed: 9.999999999999999E11
1.0E12 == 9.999999999999999E11 -> false
```

How can this be prevented so the two `double` values are equal?

**EDIT:** Linked question discusses *why* this issue appears. I am asking what are the possible ways to avoid this issue.

Comment: A cursory examination of `StreamTokenizer::nextToken` shows that it attempts to accumulate the value of all the digits sans decimal point in a `double` and then divide by a power of ten based on the number of digits to the right of the decimal point to get the correct value. Thus, "1000000000000.0000000000000" is calculated as `10000000000000000000000000. / 10000000000000`. That results in too many bits in the significand and precision is lost. The only solution I can see would be to avoid `StreamTokenizer`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This question is not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: [Appendix D: What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's all very good and well but in this case the only value being represented in floating point is an integer. The problem is different in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As per David Conrad's analysis, the `StreamTokenizer` classes handling of numbers with decimal points is flawed, and there doesn't appear to be a work-around.

But this is only one of many short-comings flaws in this class.  You would be better off using `Scanner` or `String.split`.  If the input is really complicated, consider using a parser generator to generate a lexer / parser that precisely implements your input syntax.

Related bugs:

- [JDK-4638205 : StreamTokenizer: lost precision when parsing long values](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4638205)
- [JDK-4146533 : java.io.StreamTokenizer: Want to parse scientific numbers](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4146533)
- [JDK-8180207 : deprecate StringTokenizer and StreamTokenizer](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8180207)

---

Having said that, applications that use floating point numbers should be tolerant of issues caused by rounding errors and imprecision.  There are a number of Q&As on the best way to compare floating point numbers; e.g.

- [Manipulating and comparing floating points in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896013/manipulating-and-comparing-floating-points-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

An exact way of representing numbers is usage of BigDecimal. Double has a certain precision and working with doubles of various precision (EX: double1=10000.0 and double2=0.0001) could result that the 0.0001 to be dropped. BigDecimal avoids that.

The disadvantages of BigDecimal:

- it's slower
- operators  +, -, *, and / are not overloaded

But if you are dealing with money or having precision is a must, you should use BigDecimal, otherwise you will have losses. 
EX:

```
String str = "1.0E12";
double initial = 1000000000000.0000000000000;
BigDecimal exVal = new BigDecimal(str);
System.out.println("Original: " + str);
System.out.println("Parsed: " + exVal);
System.out.println(initial + " == " + exVal + " -> " + (initial == exVal.doubleValue()));
```

Program output:

```
Original: 1.0E12
Parsed: 1.0E+12
1.0E12 == 1.0E+12 -> true
```